# Keras GAN with multiple output from generator and discriminator respectively

Tags: keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am using Keras to model GAN, and I need to combine two losses as I have two outputs. One output is from Discriminator, which is denoted as "label" in the following code, and another is from Generator, which is denoted as "Bloss". So is it possible to train the combined model of GAN (combine Generator and Discriminator) with two outputs from G and D respectively?

```
    input = Input(shape=self.input_shape)
    output_G, Bloss = self.G(input)

    # For the combined model we will only train the generator
    self.D.trainable = False

    label = self.D(output_G)

    self.combined = Model(inputs=input,
                          outputs=[label, Bloss])
    self.combined.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy', B_loss],
                          optimizer='RMSprop',
                          loss_weights=[1,0.01])
...
def B_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred - y_true, axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not, as long as you create a proper y that combines both the label (D output) and Bloss (partial G output).